# Regex pattern works on string but not on loaded file content

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match, file-get-contents

I want to extract words between ";" and ":" from an XML file, for example the word " Index" here

> bla bla bla ; Index : bla bla

the file is loaded by its URL using file_get_contents

```
$output = file_get_contents("https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sp%C3%A9cial:Exporter/Base_de_donn%C3%A9es");
       
 preg_match_all('/\;.[a-zA-Z]+.\:/', $output, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
 var_dump($matches);
```

The regex pattern works fine on the same file content using [regex101](https://regex101.com/) and also when I copy the text in a string variable. But the code above does Not work, it returns only the last match.

What am I doing wrong ?

PS : I also tried loading the XML file using DOMDocument.. same result.

Comment: You should do `/;[^:;]+:/`

Comment: If I understand well you want to extract: `Index`, `Vue matérialisée`, `Partitionnement`, `[[RAID (informatique)|RAID]] (''Redundant array of inexpensive disks'')`, `Table de Hashage  (anglais ''hashing'')`, ..., `Journal`

Comment: I only want to extract words or set of words, without any special characters or numbers.. that's why I use [a-zA-Z]

Comment: and the regex I'm using works fine, that's not the issue..

Comment: I think it should work too, simply because this pattern works fine with other regex engines.  Do you have an option to use `regex` module instead of `re` ?

Comment: @sweaver2112: note that this is a PHP question, not a Python question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do it with a low memory footprint, several considerations:

- the file is big (not enormous but big).
- the fact that your are dealing with an xml file isn't very important for this case since the text you are looking for follows it's own line based format *([XWiki format](http://platform.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Main/XWikiSyntax) for standard definitions)* that is independent of the xml format. *However, if you absolutely want to use an XML parser here to extract the `text` tag content, I suggest to use XMLReader in place of DOMDocument.*
- the lines you are looking for are always single lines, start with `;` *(without indentation)* and are always immediately followed by `:` on the next line.

Once you see that *(right click, source code)*, you can choose to read the file by line (instead of loading the whole file with `file_get_contents`) and to use a generator function to select interesting lines:

```
$url = 'https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sp%C3%A9cial:Exporter/Base_de_donn%C3%A9es';

$handle = fopen($url, 'rb');

function filterLines($handle) {
    while (feof($handle) !== true) {
        $line = fgets($handle);
        if ( $line[0] == ';' ) {
            $temp = $line;
            continue;
        } 
        if ( $line[0] == ':' && $temp )
            yield $temp;            

        $temp = false;
    }
}

foreach (filterLines($handle) as $line) {
    if ( preg_match_all('~\b\p{Latin}+(?: \p{Latin}+)*\b~u', $line, $matches) )
        echo implode(', ', $matches[0]), PHP_EOL;
}

fclose($handle);
```

Comment: "the lines you are looking for are always single lines, start with ; (without indentation) and are always immediately followed by : on the next line." - this doesn't appear to be correct.

Comment: @sweaver2112: you are not looking to the code source (what you see is the xml with the default style of your browser): right click and display the code source.

Comment: but even with a start-of-line anchor, all patterns I've tried timeout on regex101.com with python (all others work just fine).  gotta be a bug in `re` here ??

Comment: I don't know, I haven't seen your patterns, note also that the string is very large. This one works with pcre: https://regex101.com/r/CQy2wj/1/

Comment: I don't have to use an XML parser.. just mentioned the fact that I tried it, since I couldn't figure out the problem.. Thank you so much for the clear answer :) it works fine.